# Is there a place for questions about web original content? (I.E. webcomics, YouTube, etc.)

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Is there a site for asking questions about web-original content? So for example, questions about:

- Webcomics like [XKCD](https://xkcd.com), [Homestuck](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6), and [Romantically Apocolyptic](http://romanticallyapocalyptic.com/archives).
- YouTube channels and web series like [Red vs. Blue](http://roosterteeth.com/show/red-vs-blue) (RvB), [SiIvaGunner](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9ecwl3FTG66jIKA9JRDtmg), and [The Angry Video Game Nerd](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angry_Video_Game_Nerd)
- Other web originals like [Welcome to Night Vale](http://www.welcometonightvale.com)

Initially I thought questions about webseries like RvB may have fit [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com), but there didn't seem to be a community for that type of content there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head... Not yet. Feels like there are multiple possible sites.

I don't even think there's a 'proper' place for graphics novels/comics of the online or dead tree format. I suppose anime and manga covers a very small subset of comics, but none of those you mention. (I'm surprised. XKCD is quite literally a geek cultural touchstone.)

Likewise, while quite a few web-series made the leap to TV, it's kind of in that funny place where they don't have the same wide audience in popular culture.

Podcasts (*Welcome to Night Vale* and *Serial count*) are a whole different kettle of fish. And once again, has its own audience.

They do have potential to be potential sites, or possibly partially or completely fit into existing sites.

Answer (score 2):

You could try posting questions about the webcomics over on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). Yes, that may sound strange. But we've established that comics are on-topic, so you can try to push the boundaries of our scope.

Alternatively, there's a [Comics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106013/comics?referrer=O-gl6OxAUH0Ah-qS0bGf-Q2) proposal over at Area 51, where they would almost definitely on topic.